# How do you handle DB deadlocks in MVC apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deadlock

I have a Ruby on Rails application with models, controllers and stuff, so user requests are performed as independent ones. The app is backed by an MS SQL database. From time to time (at ~100 rpm) concurrent user requests cause deadlocks on DB resources, so one of the requests fails with an error.

What is the right way to handle such situations and avoid deadlocks? I'm looking for a general direction to dig. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2014/11/13/preventing-mysql-deadlocks/) has some very good advice for preventing deadlocks in Rails and dealing with them.

There is also a drop-in [deadlock_retry](https://github.com/heaps/deadlock_retry) gem written by, among others, DHH, which will re-try transactions 3 times when a deadlock timeout is detected.